# WebAPI Validation Decorations - difference between [DataMember] and [Required]?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    [Required]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

The goal here is to tell WebAPI via the DataMember decorations that all I need on the wire is Title - the other two properties are not required for a valid request.

I'm then trying to tell Entity Framework / SQL that the other properties are required in the database.  I will assign them in my service or webapi layers.

If I use the following to send only the title, I get

> {"$id":"1","message":"The request is
>   invalid.","modelState":{"$id":"2","video.VideoId":["A value is
>   required."],"video.UserId":["The UserId property is required."]}}

What am I misunderstanding here?  As far as I know, WebAPI shouldn't care that a videoId wasn't provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the `RequiredAttribute` is used solely for model validation where as the `IsRequired` property of the `DataMemberAttribute` is a hint to the serializer that says "upon serialization or deserialization, this property should always be present".

The `DataMemberAttribute` has no effect on the [`ModelStateDictionary.IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property and in the general MVC / Web Api model validation.

In your scenario, you need the [`RequiredAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) (or any of the validation attribute in the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) namespace)

**Edit:**

Ideally, you should use different model, suited for your Api's endpoint and not your Entity Framework's model directly. Because Entity Framework code-first use the same attributes as the MVC / Web Api for validation, you can't mix the two if they don't translate one on one. In my opinion, you should create a separate class for the request in your controller. For example:

```
public class VideoModel
{
    public int? VideoId { get; set; }

    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

}

// And your method
public HttpResponseMessage YourAction(VideoModel model)
{
    // Manipulate your model and map them to your Entity Framework's model
}
```

Note that the use of `int?`. If they are not required and left as an `int`, it will default to `0`. Either you leave `VideoModel` as an int and treat 0 as a special value (but then, how will you differentiate a request that genuinely sent `0`) or you use `int?.HasValue` to know if it was sent with the request.

Comment: any idea why I'm running into the above issue then?  From what you said I *believe* I'm using them correctly...

Comment: @RobVious See my edit. It somehow eluded me that you were using your Entity Framework's model directly.

Comment: I really hate the idea of having to duplicate my models... if only the attributes could work as you'd expect

Comment: @RobVious It works exactly as it's expected. The problem is that you want to use one class that model the same thing, but doesn't mean the same in every context you want to use them: one has all the field required, and one doesn't. In most cases, it's better to model your class for a web request based on that request. If the classes have the same field, you can use AutoMapper to ease manual conversion pain.